# Embed HTML form in email

Tags: html, email, forms

Can I send an email that contains an HTML form with one combobox, that upon changing the value a reply would be send back?

From the research I've made it seems that it is not possible...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_e-mail
Is that true?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes that is true. It is not possible. What you can do is provide a link to a webpage and do the combobox action on that website.

Comment: It is possible and is done all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
But there are restrictions.Different mail clients and web mails behave in different manners.

For example, Yahoo web mail, upon submitting form brings up a dialog box which warns about sending some info outside Yahoo. You have to disable Javascript if you want your submission work properly, otherwise it doesn't send submit buttons by REQUEST (POST or GET).
In outlook express I checked and it works without any problem.

Because of this problem, I think it isn't recommendable to do form embedding inside email. I suggest to make a web form and send a link to it via email. Although by this approach you may lose some lazier users, but it seems that lose will be lesser than lose arising from problems of email embedded form submission.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a form in google docs and share it via 'email', I have tested it and it shown inline at-least in gmail.

https://docs.google.com/forms

Comment: 'google link' is now 404 and bog page seems to link to the comments only(!)

Comment: @artfulrobot changed link